# What is Gauri (Gowri) Ganesh?

Tags: ganesha, festivals

It is usually celebrated a day before **Ganesh Chaturthi**.
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gowri_Habba)
states below

> This festival celebrates the goddess Gowri or Gauri, (also known as
> Parvati) who is venerated as the mother of Lord Ganesh. It is usually
> observed by married women and is a significant festival in
> Karnataka.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gowri_Habba) It is known as Hartalika in the North Indian states of
> Uttar Pradesh, Bihar, Jharkhand, Rajasthan, Chhattisgarh, Maharashtra
> and Madhya Pradesh.

What I have heard from my grandfather is that this is the day Gauri (Goddess Parvati) created Ganesh to guard her while she bathed. Story goes Lord Shiva unaware of this boy beheads and them attaches with Elephant head. Hence the next day Ganesh Chaturthi.
Here I am adding the [link](https://www.biodiversityofindia.org/index.php?title=How_Lord_Ganesha_got_his_elephant_head) to the story I just narrated above.

Is this day celebrated in other states? If so what is the significance.

Comment: That festival is more commonly known as हरितालिका व्रत,  and is celebrated across india

Comment: And parvati devi did this vrat to get lord shiva while she was unmarried, and it was named hartalika as her friends went to a forest as parvati devi didn't wanted to marry lord vishnu

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi I did  not know about this Hartalika Vrth, It is not celebrated in southern states